# Python read csv fuction

Tags: python, typeerror

I wrote this code:

```
def somefile (filename, separator, quote):
"""
read csv fuction
"""
with open (filename,newline= '') as csv_file:
    firstrow= []
    csv_reader= csv.reader(filename, delimeter= separator, quotechar=quote)
    firstrow= csv_reader[0]
return fieldnames

print (somefile("example.csv",',', '|'))
```

but python returns me the following error:
**TypeError: 'delimeter' is an invalid keyword argument for this function**

Why does python not accept comma as a delimiter with this arguments?

Comment: `delimiter` not `delimeter`.

Comment: It pays to read the error message closely and try to understand what it's saying. Error messages aren't there just to annoy you - they're there to be helpful and tell you what is wrong with your code. Furthermore, if you don't understand what the error means, google it. This particular error has lots of results on google as it's a common spelling mistake, and others have asked the same question.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) you'll see that the keyword argument you're after is 'delimiter'.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through official python documentation https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html. The main reason behind this error is spelling mistakes in line

```
csv_reader= csv.reader(filename, delimeter= separator, quotechar=quote)
```

it should be,

```
csv_reader= csv.reader(filename, delimiter= separator, quotechar=quote)
```